# Hazelcast Predicate in clause

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

Can anyone tell me how to 'in' clause with Hazelcast predicate. I want to use the following,

```
Predicates.in('column',value);
```

I want to pass the value as an ArrayList of values. But it is throwing error as it expects object that implements comparable. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicates.in takes arguments of types (String, Comparable...).

So for the column name you pass a String as you have done.
Comparable... means you can pass the individual values in a comma-separated list, but you can also pass them in an array.   An ArrayList won't automatically be converted, but you can do it as follows:

```
ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
Predicates.in("column", values.toArray(new String[]));
```

The (new String[]) argument is just to ensure you get back an array of Strings, otherwise you'll get an array of Objects.